# Imagick no longer works

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have some code, that used to work, bur for some reason no longer does.

```
$thumb = new Imagick();
$thumb->readImage($path);
$thumb->thumbnailImage(0, 50);
$thumb->writeImage($newpath."50/".$SubPath."/".$file[count($file)-1]);
```

At the first line I get Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found

If I run this code

```
function alist ($array) {  
  $alist = "<ul>";
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
$alist .= "<li>$array[$i]";
  }
  $alist .= "</ul>";
  return $alist;
}
//Try to get ImageMagick "convert" program version number.
exec("convert -version", $out, $rcode);
 //Print the return code: 0 if OK, nonzero if error. 
echo "Version return code is $rcode <br>"; 
//Print the output of "convert -version"    
echo alist($out);
```

I can see this

Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-7 2012-06-21 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP

So ImageMagick should be installed.

Comment: There is a difference between the Imagemagick on you server (`exec("convert -version", $out, $rcode);`) and the installed PHP extension (`$thumb = new Imagick();`). You need the Imagemagick PHP extension.

Comment: It used to work. Does it mean that Imagick is no longer installed?

Comment: This means the Imagemagick PHP Extension is not installed.